# How to keep just the last cached query in Apollo client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a paginated graphQL-Query in my react app, which can paginate thousands of rows. The pagination is processed at server.
Now I want to use fetchPolicy `cache-first`, to be able to load a paginationQuery from cache, if i.e. user returns from back to a visited route which uses the paginated data.

This works, but to not overload the memory, I don't want to keep every ROOT_QUERY in cache (over time, the more often the user displays his data differently (different page, different sorting, different filter, etc. ...), the cache would grow immensely). How can I achieve to keep just the last cached query.

i.e.

```js
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQL_QUERY, {
    variables,
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
    onCompleted: () => {
      //clear old cached versions of my GQL_QUERY no matter what parameters
    }
  });
```

Thanks